# Group Numbers based on Level

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have requirement in SQL Server database where I have to group the data. please find the image attached for reference.

If the Level is more than 2 then it has to be grouped under level 2 (ex: 1.1.1, 1.1.2 are rolled up under 1.1.) and if there isn't any level 2 available then have to create a second level based on the level 3 Numbers (ex: 1.2.1)

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to add an additional column as per your screenshot, do you want to group the data and do aggregations on it or do you simply want to order the data when output?

Comment: is there always a `.` at the end of a groupnumber for Level 2 or higher? Because 1.2.1 doesn't have one.

Comment: please paste data as text

Comment: @iamdave: yes i want the exact replica of what is show in the image. A new column with all level 3 and above numbers.

Comment: @Nebi: Yes the number always end with a dot (ex: 1.2.1.).

Comment: @TheGameiswar: Column  Derived Col1 Derived Col 2
1  1 
1.1.  1.1. 
1.1.1.  1.1. 1.1.1.
1.1.2.  1.1. 1.1.2.
1.2.1  1.2. 1.2.1
1.3.  1.3. 
1.3.1.  1.3. 1.3.1.
1.3.2.  1.3. 1.3.2.
1.4.1.  1.4. 1.4.1..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not certain that the first 2 numbers are single digits:

```
declare @T table ([Column] varchar(20));

insert into @T values ('1'),('1.2.'),('1.2.3.'),('1.2.3.4.'),('10.20.'),('10.20.30.'),('10.20.30.40.');

select 
case when [Column] like '%.%.%' then substring([Column],1,charindex('.',[Column],charindex('.',[Column])+1)) else [Column] end as [Derived Col1], 
case when [Column] like '%.%.%.%' then [Column] else '' end as [Derived Col2]
from @T;
```

If it's certain that the first 2 numbers are single digits then it can be simplified:

```
declare @T table ([Column] varchar(20));

insert into @T values ('1'),('1.2.'),('1.2.3.'),('1.2.3.4.');

select 
substring([Column],1,4) as [Derived Col1], 
case when [Column] like '%.%.%.%' then [Column] else '' end as [Derived Col2]
from @T;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this do, if you need the new values as computed columns?

**Updated**: this works with double digits and the third column is null for 1st/2nd level version

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    Version varchar(30),
    VersionMain AS CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('.',Version,4) > 0 THEN LEFT(Version,CHARINDEX('.',Version,4)) ELSE Version END,
    VersionSub AS CASE
        WHEN LEN(Version) - LEN(REPLACE(Version,'.','')) >= 3 THEN Version ELSE NULL END
)
```

Comment: do we have a dynamic way of getting the number used in LEFT function.

Comment: The left part is a bit tricky, but you actually have to implement same sort of logic into the subvalue as well (when version numbers go over 9). The sub part is easy using case logic WHEN LEN(Version) - REPLACE(Version,'.','') >= 3

Answer (score 0):

you can use CHARINDEX to locate '.' and then decide DERIVED_COL_2.

```
SELECT COLUMN, 
SUBSTRING(COLUMN,1,4)DERIVED_COL_1,
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',COLUMN,5) = 6 THEN COLUMN END AS DERIVED_COL_2
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```